# Returning The Name of the highest value field

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 4 field of Numeric Values, I want Excel To pick the highest value of them and show me the name of the field that is related to the highest one, for example:

```
Option 1 (J10)     Option2 (K10)     Option3(L10)     Option4(M10)
```

and the values are :

```
50(J15)          60(K15)            70(L15)          65(M15)
```

I want Excel to return ( Option 3) instead of showing me the number 70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

`=INDEX(J10:M10,MATCH(MAX(J15:M15),J15:M15,0))`

Comment: I use the combination of `INDEX` & `MATCH` all the time when looking up disparate columns (or rows) of data. Microsoft should make a variation of `VLOOKUP` & `HLOOKUP` that handles this kind of thing. It would be much easier.

Comment: I suppose `LOOKUP` is close enough to that except that it assumed the data is sorted

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` command does **not** require the data to be sorted as long as you put `FALSE` as the last parameter.

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to `LOOKUP`.

Comment: Oops, yes, my mistake.

Comment: ..and you can use LOOKUP here, i.e. `=LOOKUP(2,1/(J15:M15=MAX(J15:M15)),J10:M10)`.....although if there are duplicate MAX values in J15:M15 you get the last match rather than first...